# Using Flow to get Lookup Column Value and use these Value to calculate

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, lookup-column, flow

I am setting a Flow that can get the value of lookup column for using in Calculated Column. My List below:

List A: Target List, contain Currencies and Exchange Rate to VND (Called exRate) of the Currencies
[image]

List B: Source List, Product List, want to calculate price in VND
[image]

I want the Column ExchangeRate in List B to get data from Lookup Column "Currencies: exRate" and the "Price in VND" column calculate = OriPrice x ExchangeRate. And when the "ExRate" in List A change, then update "Exchange Rate" and "Price in VND" column  in List B.

I want to use MS Flow and also Sharepoint Workflow 2013.

Please give me an advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems currencies is a lookup column. It can be with a flow like below.
Use the currency id to find the corresponding exRate in the currency list and set the exRate to the current item Exchange Rate column
[image]

For updating exRate when changed in the target list, you can use another flow to do so. 
[image]

About how to filter look up column, please check this:https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Flow-Ideas/SharePoint-ODATA-filtering-by-lookup-values/idi-p/152553

Comment: Hi @jerry_MSFT, I success with the First Workflow. But the 2nd WorkFlow, what is the Trigger of the Workflow? Sorry bro, I am a newbie.

Comment: @TANEZVISA, The second flow is triggered by item is created/modified in the currencies list, which is your list a

Comment: Thanks, @jerry_MSFT. You are the one who saved me

Comment: @TANEZVISA Glad to help. Please accept the reply as answer so other people could find it more easily